# how to enable/disable auto keylock in android

Tags: android

Hi i am developing a clock application in android. I need to lock the screen after some amount of time duration like 5 minutes, or 10 minutes. how can i call the auto lock of the android os. Please suggest me to lock the home screen after a particular amoutn of time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find the answer to your question by reading this page here:

[How to lock the screen of an android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6762671/how-to-lock-screen-android)