# How to disable unlocking screen programmatically

Tags: android, lockscreen

1. I need to lock the Android phone when the user leaves a defined WiFi area
2. I need to prevent the user from unlocking the phone when he/she is out side the defined WiFi area
3. I need to unlock the phone when user is back to the WiFi area

I guess list items 1 and 3 can be done programmatically.

Is it possible to do the 2<sup>nd</sup> item?

Comment: +1, interesting question. (I wouldn't have marked up the numbers as inline code though, it looks odd)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I need to prevent the user from unlocking the phone when he/she is out side the defined WiFi area

Fortunately, this is not supported, for obvious security reasons.

You are welcome to create your own home screen that offers different behavior when inside/outside a defined area and use that in lieu of trying to prevent a phone from being unlocked. However, the user is welcome to remove that home screen by booting their device into safe mode and uninstalling your app.

Answer (score 6):

Locking can be done using this method: [How to lock the screen of an android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6762671/how-to-lock-screen-android)
Unlocking look here: [How to display Activity when the screen is locked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793221/how-my-app-can-unlock-screen-programatically)

For your problem 2, i see 2 solutions

a. If the user unlocks the screen, a message is fired: check at that moment if you are in the area and if not, instantly lock again

b. create your own locksreen with no possibility to unlock yourself

Answer (score 3):

I had done similar thing in past but dont have the code right now so cant help in that respect. What I did is implement the app as Car Dock that will make the Home button override unless car-dock mode is dis-abled. I hope this will help, for code google it you definitely find resources

Answer (score 1):

I guess this will help you out. This is just for `Disabling` the Lock `Programmatically`.[Disable Screen Lock](http://www.androidsnippets.com/disable-initial-screen-lock)

Answer (score 0):

```
private Window w;
```

public void onResume() {

```
    w = this.getWindow();
    w.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
    w.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
    w.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
    super.onResume();       
    tToast("onResume");
}
```