# lock screen sometime not display android

Tags: android

i created lock screen application.. Sometimes it give me a problem. problem is that some time default lock screen display rather than my lock screen and some time directly home screen display. i donot know where is the problem. please give me suggestion about this.

LockScreenActivity:
Use

```
KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Activity.KEYGUARD_SERVICE); 
KeyguardLock lock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE); 
lock.disableKeyguard();
```

and create ScreenReceiver:

```
ACTION_SCREEN_OFF
ACTION_SCREEN_ON
ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED
```

Refer this link: http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/

in manifeast file : declare service and receiver and permission

The problem is in BroadcastReceiver when

```
if (recievedIntent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
    //call activity
}else if (recievedIntent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
}
```

but the activity call after screen on.. so what is missing or what is problem.. why it is happn pls rply.

Hi here is my code :

```
public class myReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static boolean wasScreenOn = true;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent recievedIntent) {

        if (recievedIntent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            wasScreenOn = false;

            Intent intent = new Intent(context,
                    myActivity.class);
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_USER_ACTION);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            intent.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
                    context.startActivity(intent
                    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));

        } else if (recievedIntent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            wasScreenOn = true;
        }
    }
}
```

The activity is calling after when action screen on is call .

Comment: how can you expect a suggestion without making your problem clear..? show some code too....

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6762671/how-to-lock-screen-android

Comment: hi thanks for reply but not getting any success.

Comment: post your implemented code if possible.

Comment: hi  i posted my code please check and tell me where i am doing mistake.